# Where can I download a base map like this one?

Tags: qgis, basemap

I'm trying to find a base map similar to this one（monochromatic, terrain/river only）, but I haven't found a downloadable resource.
Can anyone provide information about it?

[image]

Comment: _"Similar to this one"_ ? ... What does that mean ? What are you looking for ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe it clearly. I need to find this monochromatic, terrain/river only map.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to download and use one of the 1:10 million rasters from Natural Earth, like [this one](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-gray-earth):
Then your problem is how to reproduce this projection, which I cannot assist with, other than to say it looks like an Albers projection, which you could research.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try Albers.